Automatically fill in if product is in spec or not
I'm trying to make a table where when I enter a specific range of numbers, say 6.75-8.25 in 1 column and 10.35-12.65 in the other columns in "size" and then enter a number in the Length row it is then automatically picked up in the "in spec/oos" column to determine if the number entered is in spec or not by a percentage, I.e if the rest of the table is filled out in length row 1-10 and 4 are out of spec range its automatically picked up in the in spec/oos column as 40%.
The numbers in the size columns need to be able to change as I'll need to duplicate this table over and over. Is this a do able thing?

I'm a newbie when it comes to Excel. I can do the basics but nothing extreme like this so any helps appreciated
